# Why does the program show the text only after I press Ctrl+S?

Tags: flutter

I want my program to print the text "Data has been inserted!" if I get a positive response from the database. It works perfectly except the fact that it doesn't show the text only if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Or maybe how can I tell the program to Ctrl+S automaticly?

(please ignore the other Widgets and variables, I didn't put all of them)

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks! :)

```
Widget _buildInsertedData(){
    if(b==1){
      print('1');
      return Text(
        'Data has been inserted!',
      );
    }
    else{
      return Text(' ');
    }
  }
```

In _buildInsertedData(), I return the Text(' ') so that when the program first runs it wont show anything. This might not be the best way of doing it.
(you can scroll down till the end of the 'build' Widget, that's where the '_buildInsertedData()' is called).

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    email=ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    email=email["email"];
   // print(email);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'OrderLunch',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 26.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 595,
        width: 800,

        ///not accurate
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/portocale.jpg'),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3.5,
                  color: Colors.blue[400],
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(15),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              //color: Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                'copil/copii:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 23.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            SizedBox(height: 270, child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getMethod(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                List snap = snapshot.data;
                if(bool1==0){
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('Error fatching Data!'),
                    );
                  }
                  catiCopii=snap.length;
                  bool1=1;
                }
                //print('hi');
                if (catiCopii == 1) {
                  elev1nume = snap[0]['elevNume'];
                  elev1prenume = snap[0]['elevPrenume'];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('         '),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "$elev1nume $elev1prenume:",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 22.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('         '),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'Ii se va comanda maine mancare:',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text('  '),
                            _buildFirstDate(),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }


                else {
                  ///sunt 2 sau mai multi copii
                  if(bool==0){
                    elev1nume = snap[0]['elevNume'];
                    elev1prenume = snap[0]['elevPrenume'];
                    elev2nume = snap[1]['elevNume'];
                    elev2prenume = snap[1]['elevPrenume'];
                    bool=1;
                  }
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('         '),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "$elev1nume $elev1prenume:",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 22.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('         '),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'Ii se va comanda maine mancare:',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text('  '),
                            _buildFirstDate(),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('         '),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "$elev2nume $elev2prenume:",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 22.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('         '),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'Ii se va comanda maine mancare:',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text('  '),
                            _buildSecondDate(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            )
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            RaisedButton (
              color: Colors.blue[400],
              child: Text(
                'Save changes',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if(catiCopii==1)
                  updateMethod1();
                else{
                  updateMethod1();
                  updateMethod2();
                }
                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
                  if (b == 1) {
                    _buildInsertedData();
                    print(':)');
                    //b = 0;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
            _buildInsertedData(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is `b` and when are you setting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because `_buildInsertedData` returns a widget, which you have also added to your tree - which is correct. But calling that function on onPressed doesn't update the widget in the tree. When you press the button it updates the value but you're not rebuilding the widget tree until you press Ctrl-S.

To rebuild the tree you can call

```
setState(() { 
   //  you can set any new values here (but not necessary)
 });
```

So maybe you want to do it like this:

```
 onPressed: ......
 // b gets updated somewhere here before the future
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
              if (b == 1) {
                setState(() {    }); // rebuilds tree on screen
              }
            });
```

You're also checking if `b==1` twice - consider removing one :)